# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Check existing or available Topics

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've read on Google Firebase Docs:

> Client apps can subscribe to any existing topic, or they can create a new topic.

So how can I can check how many existing topics are available for me? Is it only through the console? Or is there an API?

Comment: There is no public API to get a list of topics. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874606/how-to-get-all-topics-list-of-firebase-through-api

Comment: There is api to list existing or available Topics.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987821/get-all-subscribed-topics-from-firebase-cloud-messaging

Comment: Please take a look to my answer to a similar questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948720/is-there-anyway-to-access-the-firebase-topics-a-user-is-subscribed-to/47835894#47835894

Comment: Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987821/get-all-subscribed-topics-from-firebase-cloud-messaging/65301320#65301320

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already mentioned by @FrankvanPuffelen in the comments section, there is not available API to get a list of Topics you have.

What you could do is keep record of the topics you have created on your server side. So it pretty much depends on your own implementation.

Also, if you are thinking of checking the number of subscribers of a specific topic so you can see which ones are active or not, it's also not possible. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38379251/4625829) by @ArthurThompson:

> No. There is no current way to query the number of subscribers to a topic, **you would have to maintain the relationship between token and topics on you app server**.