# How to get client FCM tokens from a FCM topic

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to get the tokens list inside the FCM topic. Basically I want the list of token subscribed to a FCM topic.

Basically I want the registered client token from a FCM topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase (FCM) how to get token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787373/firebase-fcm-how-to-get-token)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no public API to retrieve the list of tokens that are subscribed to a topic. If you want such a list, you'll have to maintain it yourself.

Also see:

- [List of clients who have registered for a topic in FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592342/list-of-clients-who-have-registered-for-a-topic-in-fcm)
- [Count subscribers of a topic in Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851105/count-subscribers-of-a-topic-in-firebase-cloud-messaging/40861417)
- [Firebase Cloud Messaging - Check existing or available Topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623742/firebase-cloud-messaging-check-existing-or-available-topics/39632704#39632704)

Comment: Can I subscribe a topic to another topic?

Comment: No. But you can send a single message to multiple topics with conditions, which probably accomplishes what you need. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_topics