# Unsubscribe all users from a topic in FCM

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to unsubscribe all users from a topic in Firebase Cloud messaging without knowing the tokens? Basically, "delete" the topic?

It would be really really painful to do this manually since it should happen with a document change trigger, meaning the function would somehow have to know all the user tokens. So it's either a function/set of functions for "get all tokens for topic, then unsubscribe all of them", or "delete topic". Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to unsubscribe all tokens from a specific topic. There also is no API to get a list of tokens for a topic. See [How to get client FCM tokens from a FCM topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533735/how-to-get-client-fcm-tokens-from-a-fcm-topic)

Topics are automatically created and deleted by Firebase Cloud Messaging. A topic is created when you first subscribe a token to it, or send a message to it. And it's essentially deleted when you remove the last token from it.

Comment: It sure would be nice to have an API for that. I'm going to do a feature request.

Comment: Hi Frank. Has this feature been added yet?

Comment: Nope. I don't expect this feature to be added any time soon, as the topics tend to disappear over time as you stop sending messages to it.