# GUI for removing Firebase cloud messaging subscriptions

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm debugging firebase notifications with my colleagues and I want to try a new approach knowing that all previous subscriptions have been removed.

We subscribe by POSTing to `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/<token>/rel/topics/<topic>`

Is there a UI I can use to remove all existing subscriptions so that I know I am testing the new code?

If not, is there some other to remove a bunch of subscriptions the details of which I do not have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no UI built into the Firebase console to remove the mappings from topics to tokens. The API you found is the only way to do so.

I typically write a small (Node.js) script to loop over the tokens/topic in my database and remove them.

Comment: ah, can you explain where the database is that has that info?

Comment: That's in your own database. There is no API to get all tokens for a topic built into FCM. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533735/how-to-get-client-fcm-tokens-from-a-fcm-topic