# How to check the number of clients subscribed to a FCM Topic?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way I can check the number of clients who have subscribed to a particular FCM topic on Android ?

Comment: Yes doable @Hitesh

Comment: The Firebase API does not expose a way to get the number of subscribers for a topic. If you want such information, you'll have to record it yourself.. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40851105/count-subscribers-of-a-topic-in-firebase-cloud-messaging