# Firebase Cloud Messaging topic stats API

Tags: api, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can't find if there's any API endpoint to get some stats about the FCM topics

I would like to know how many users (and possibly their tokens) have been suscribed to a specific topic

Answer (score 0):

There is no available API to check how many subscribers a topic has. You'll have to implement the mapping on your server-side. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40861417/4982169 for more details