# How to get number of subscribed devices to specific topic in FCM?

Tags: parse-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are migrating from Parse to FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).

Parse has a great endpoint we've used to get the number of devices subscribed to specific topic (Parse calls is channel):
https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#querying-installations

I cannot find it's equivalent in FCM. I know there is Firebase Analytics dashboard, but I'm looking for API endpoint.

Does FCM provide any API endpoints which could be used for analytics purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no current way to get the number of subscribers of a topic in FCM. See @ArthurThompson's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38379251/4625829).

> No. There is no current way to query the number of subscribers to a topic, you would have to maintain the relationship between token and topics on you app server.

For your analytics inquiry, are you refering to an API where you can retrieve logs/details for your FCM messages? If so, you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40341195/4625829).